# How to automate wordpress installation in subdomain

Tags: multisite

How can I automate the installation of wordpress in a subdomain?

Example:

Upon registration user1 would get automatically wordpress on user1.domain.com.

Then, upon registration user2 would get his own wordpress on user2.domain.com, etc.

I can program a little bit PHP, but I would rather avoid any programming and would prefer a ready-made solution if it exists.

Thank you in advance for your help. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Do they have to be separate wordpress installations? Depending on what you want to do, it might be better (read: more efficient) to have each user get a category or a custom post type or something. If possible, can you clarify what your end goal is?

Comment: @m0r7if3r  My goal is to create a website (based on wordpress) for each user. So I think it make sense to provide a separate wordpress install for each user. I am open to other ideas. I am still trying to figure out the best way to generate websites for users on subdomains.

Comment: Have you looked at wordpress multisite at all?

Comment: @m0r7if3r  Thanks a lot. I overlooked wordpress multisite. That's exactly what I was looking for. The only thing I still don't know is how to automatically create a new user in a wordpress multisite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to m0r7if3, I found the two pieces of information I was looking for:

- wordpress multisite
- "Automatically create a new WordPress site in your Network associated with the user that is created." -> http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/

Answer (score -1):

We created an open source script for this purpose, you can find it here http://buckhill.github.io/linux-package-installer-for-wordpress

We wrote an article on how to use it here: https://www.buckhill.co.uk/blog/how-to-automatically-install-wordpress-plus-plugins/6

If you want to contribute to the project, please go ahead :)

Comment: This purely link answers. Please file an [edit] and add the proper information and code from the links

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory.  He needs to auto install WP, and we released a free script for the community to do just that.  How else can it be explained - there's no need to post code here.